# How to get css property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am using angularjs to get a css property value but it is coming back undefined. Here is the code I am using:

```
var test = angular(document.querySelector('.mobile-menu')).attr('display');
```

This code is inside a directive.

Comment: And what is the css on that element?

Comment: Did you read here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found that even if your css class contains `display` your `test` var will be empty. you need to define it inside the style attribute of the element

```
<div class="mobile-menu" style="display: block"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var test = angular.element(document.querySelector('.mobile-menu')).css('display');
alert(test);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQtc8/

remove the style attribute from the div and test will be empty.